# find squareroot with a loop

Tags: c

```
double sqrtIt(double x, double low_guess, double high_guess) {
    int n = 10;
    int num = 0;
    while ( n > 0.000000000000001){
        n = n / 10;
        while (num < x && low_guess <= (low_guess * 10)){
            low_guess = low_guess + n;
            num = low_guess * low_guess; 
            }
    }
    return low_guess;
}
```

I've tried to use the code above to find the square root of a number. the function works fine most of the time, but when the number is 2, I get the "*There is no source code available for the current location. Show disassembly*" error from line `num = low_guess * low_guess;` I don't know what did wrong, and what does show disassembly do? Thanks

Comment: "Show dissaembly" is pretty self descriptive. It shows you the disassembly for the code (since for some reason the debugger can't show the source). This is an indication that either the crash is in library code (or code that's otherwise not yours) or that your symbols are configured incorrectly. In your case, I'd guess it's option #1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "no source code available" message may indicate that you are not compiling in debug mode, so your IDE can't do a source-level debug.  I think there's probably some confusion here, brought on by trying to deal with an IDE for the first time...

As others have said, you should probably declare n and num to be double, not int.

Probably, once you become more familiar with your development environment (as well as the language), some of these things will sort themselves out.

Answer (score 2):

There are some problems with this function, but this seems to be a very strange error to get from that code. I think you made some other error somewhere else in your program, and that error is then causing this problem.

Answer (score 1):

is there a typo in your code?
low_guess <= (low_guess * 10 ) is always true for non negative number...

Answer (score 0):

Even if it worked it would be pretty inefficient. I guess you wanted to write something like this

```
double sqrtIt(double x)
{
  double guess1, guess2;
  guess1=1.0;
  do
  {
    guess2=x/guess1;
    guess1=(guess1+guess2)/2;
  }
  while (abs(guess1,guess2)<0.0000001);
  return guess1;
}
```